# How to highlight Primeng tabpanel if any form controls values are invalid- Angular

Tags: angular, primeng, angular-reactive-forms

I have a reactive form and form controls are placed in different tab's of primeng tab panel I want to highlight with red color of tab panel if any tab panel form control is invalid. So a user idenify which tab form control is not valid

```
1. Component
             this.tankCreateForm = this.formBuilder.group({
             location: ['', [Validators.minLength(3)]],
             tankName: ['', [Validators.minLength(3)]]
            });
 2. html
          <form [formGroup]="tankCreateForm">
              <p-tabView>
                <p-tabPanel header="Tank Basic" leftIcon="pi pi-pencil">
                  <br />
                  <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-4 form-group offset-md-1">
                      <span class="ui-float-label">
                        <input id="float-input" type="text" pInputText class="form-control" formControlName="tankName">
                        <label for="float-input"><span class="mandatory">Tank Name</span></label>
                      </span>
                    </div>
                  </div>
            </p-tabPanel>
             <p-tabPanel header="Tank Advnce" leftIcon="pi pi-pencil">
                  <br />
                  <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-4 form-group offset-md-1">
                      <span class="ui-float-label">
                        <input id="float-input" type="text" pInputText class="form-control" formControlName="location">
                        <label for="float-input"><span class="mandatory">Location</span></label>
                      </span>
                    </div>
                  </div>
              </p-tabView>
```

Comment: I Would say instead of changing the color...just activate the tab in which you find invalid form value? Activating tab programatically is easy in prime-ng?

Comment: But if both tab panle invalid form controls how to do that

Comment: You should show us the code for the formgroup and formcontrols?  Do you have validation required option set for each? What are the rules?

Comment: If any user type only 2 letters in tank name field and navigated to second tab first tab should high light as red color

  this.tankCreateForm = this.formBuilder.group({
  location: ['', [Validators.minLength(3)]],
      tankName: ['', [Validators.minLength(3)]]
    });

Comment: updated issue with validator in component